# nonnegative finite-valued Borel measurable function that is not $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a counterexample

If  $\mu$ is a measure (on a $\sigma$-field $F$ of subsets of $\Omega$) and $f\colon\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nonnegative finite-valued Borel measurable function, then the measure $\lambda$ defined by

$\lambda (A)=\int_{A}f\, d\mu$

is $\sigma$-finite.

is the following answer correct?

$\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathscr{F}=\{A:A\subset\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mu$ is the counting measure. $f:=1$. Then
$$\lambda(A)=\operatorname{card}(A).$$
So $\lambda$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Definition of $\sigma$-finite: A non-negative finitely additive set function $\mu$ on a field $F$ is said to be $\sigma$-finite on $F$ iff $\Omega$  can be written as $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ where $A_{n}$ belong to $F$  and $\mu(A_{n})<\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: This counterexample looks good to me.  To fix the claim, perhaps you can assume that the  $f$ function is bounded, and $\mu$ is itself $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: For your current counterexample:  You should add some details to show that no countable set of finite-measure sets (with respect to the counting measure) can have union equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Michael That's the part that I can't find out. How do you show that  no countable set of finite-measure sets (with respect to the counting measure) can have union equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You just directly show it:  Suppose $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ is a countable collection of finite-measure sets, then...

Comment: @Michael thanks a lot. You mean I can say:  Suppose $A_{1},A_{2},…$ is a countable collection of finite-measure sets, then since countable collection of finite-measure sets is countable, it can not be equal to $R$ which is an uncountable set. Am I right?

Comment: This is not quite a good proof.  Your statement "since countable collection of finite-measure sets is countable" should be modified/clarified.  Why should this be true?  Certainly it is not true for all measures.  Where are you using the fact that we are dealing with the counting measure? So, you need to be more precise.